# Does a thin layer of glue on a food vessel disqualify it's emersion in a kaylim mikveh?

Tags: halacha, tevilas-keilim-dipping, chatzitzah

I recently purchased metal drinking bottles. I tried the best I could to remove all of the sticker that came with the purchase. A thin layer of glue remains. Can I halachically toyvel it?

Comment: Do you want the glue there?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but FYI Goo Gone is a great product for removing such substances.

Comment: No I do not want the glue there.

Comment: @msh210: as is nail polish remover

Comment: WD40 usually does the trick.